# How to install fluorinefx with support for .net framework 4.0?

Tags: .net, apache-flex, amf, fluorinefx

I'm trying to integrate Flex and .net framework 4.0 classes, weborb is way too expensive and the only other option I have stumbled upon is fluorinefx but the installer on it's website doesn't support .net 4.0 and after downloading it's source code there is no clue about how to integrate it, no documentation at all and no answer on it's forum.

Have anyone been able to do this? and if so, how?

note: XML, JSON and such are not useful for me as the apps are data intensive, I'm looking for something that does the same job as weborb, fluorinefx, blazeds, etc for .net framework 4.0, fluorinefx seemed promising until I realized the forums are dead and there is absolutely no updated documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compile the src from the [fluorinefx project](http://code.google.com/p/fluorinefx/source/checkout) on google code to get the latest dlls. You would need to generate the fluorine.snk file to build though, in SolutionExplorer->FluorineFx-4.0->Properties->Signing, or use the command line, see ../snk/fluorine.snk.readme for details or [How to: Sign an Assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247123.aspx).

Otherwise you can use the .NET 3.5 libraries with 4.0, either by converting a 3.5 template project to 4.0 or linking a 4.0 project to the old dlls and adding the relevant fluorinefx configs to your web.config.

Comment: I DID compile those 4.0 libraries, but then I don't know what to do with them, do you know of any docs about that part?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if you missed it, WebORB Community Edition is absolutely free and does support .NET Framework 4.0. See this for more details: http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products/weborb-for-net/producteditions.html

Comment: I have used it and it's wonderful, except that I need to implement on lots of servers and in a 3rd world country, paying the license is a dead end (price is thought for US it seems, with the money needed to deploy in 1 server I can sustain my family 4 months)

Answer (score -1):

You dont have to use WebOrb or FlorineFx (both AMF options), you could use a regular HttpService set up in C#, with an ASP page to handle the communication to the SWF. There should be a good few tutorials if you search.

We did something similar to communicate between Air and C#, using a HttpListener in C# and posting requests from air to the listening port.

**Edit:** Heres an [example](http://nishadmusthafa.wordpress.com/2009/10/08/net-based-httpservice-accessed-from-a-flex-application-using-the-data-centric-development-dcd-in-flash-builder-4/) for you

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for amf remoteobject system, I need to be able to call .net methods and communicate via amf because httpservice is bandwidth and time inefficient.